# BottomNavigationView Is hiding my webview

Tags: android, webview, bottomnavigationview

I have a  BottomNavigationView activity . in that, i have a webview fragment, whenever the web-view loads a website. The BottomNavigationView is hiding the bottom part of my web-view, is there anyone who can help me regarding this ?

this is my activity_main.xml which contain the BottomNavigationView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.polysocial.MainActivity">




<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my first fragment code which contain the webview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.polysocial.tab2">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:foregroundGravity="top"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress"
        android:progress="20"/>

</FrameLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.polysocial.EulaWebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Refer the screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You just neet to add a FrameLayout (It will be you container so keep its id as  android:id="@+id/container")**

> and replace your code of activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        >

    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: when ever the user scroll down the webview my application is hiding the actionbar, but when hides , it irritates the the bottom navigation, why ?

Answer (score 0):

Actully you are adding your your fragment on all your layout which is below the navigation below. you should use layout like below and place your fragment within inner layout.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/navigation"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--Your code for the fragment here.-->
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i hv replaced wit your code in activity_main.xml, but the navigation view is gone

Comment: it works after adding app:menu="@menu/navigation" , but same problem happening

Comment: simple shift the android:id="@+id/container" line to inner relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

use 
android_layout_height="50dp" (in bottom navigation)

and use 
android_layoutmarginBottom="50dp"  (in web view)

hope it helps.